# Ubuntu 12.10 headphone faint beep on audio start and stop

Tags: 12.10, sound, headphones

I was wondering if anyone had experienced this before and if there was a fix for it.
Whenever I play a video or any music, my headphones produce a faint beep whenever the audio starts or stops, the beep sometimes happens after loading a webpage as well.  I don't think its my headphones, because this didn't happen when I had Windows installed before making the switch to Ubuntu. It's almost as if the sound card turns off and then turns on again when I want to play audio. Maybe there is a way to keep it on always? I am running Ubuntu 12.10